# Parse CulterInfo to dll once

Tags: c#, dll

I have a little application which has 1 GUI `Form` and 1 `Class Library`. Inside my Class Library I have a `Class` named "Settings". Settings has a `String Property` "CulterInfo".

This is code from `GUI.frm` *(code 1)*

```
Base.Settings.CultureInfo = "en-US";
ExceptionHandler.test(new EventArgs());
```

This is code from `Base.dll` *(code 2)*

```
static ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Languages.Language", System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Languages.dll"));
static CultureInfo cul = new CultureInfo(Settings.CultureInfo);
public static void test(EventArgs e)
{
    ParseException(null, new ExceptionHandlerEventArgs() { ExceptionMessage = rm.GetString("exDefault", cul) });
}
```

And this is code for the "Settings" `Class` *(code 3)*

```
public class Settings
{
    private static string cultureInfo;
    public static string CultureInfo { get { return cultureInfo; } set { cultureInfo = value; } }
}
```

When I do like above, I get an error. The reason is because `CulterInfo` is actually still nothing tho I use `Base.Settings.CultureInfo = "en-US";`.

When I comment `Base.Settings.CultureInfo = "en-US";` in *code 1* and do `private static string cultureInfo = "en-US";` in *code 3* it's working.

---

So what my main problem is, I want to set the `CultureInfo` once for the `dll` I'm using, but this is not working like I hoped it would. Is there a better way to set the `CultureInfo` for a `dll` once, like at the startup of the application, and never have to bother about it anymore?

---

EDIT 1: Would working with a configfile solve this or are there more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `static CultureInfo cul = new CultureInfo(Settings.CultureInfo);` is likely to be initialized before you update your `Base.Settings.CultureInfo`.

You can initialize the static `CultureInfo` with an `InvariantCulture`, and update it before using the `dll`

```
//Code 3
public class Settings
{
    private static CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    public static CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get { return culture; }
        set { culture = value; }
    }

    public static void SetCulture(string name)
    {
        culture = new CultureInfo(name);
    }
}
```

```
//code 2
public class ExceptionHandler
{
    static ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Languages.Language", System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Languages.dll"));

    public static void test(EventArgs e)
    {
        ParseException(null, new ExceptionHandlerEventArgs() { ExceptionMessage = rm.GetString("exDefault", Settings.Culture) });
    }
}
```

```
//code 1
/*Base.Settings.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");*/ //or...
Base.Settings.SetCulture("en-US");
ExceptionHandler.test(new EventArgs());
```

Comment: Yup, that did it for me, tnx.